# What does void do in java?

Tags: java, void

> The return type—the data type of the value returned by the method, or void if the method does not return a value.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Okay, then.. Here is my question:

```
public class EnumTest {
    Day day;

    public EnumTest(Day day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public void tellItLikeItIs() {
        switch (day) {
            case MONDAY: System.out.println("Mondays are bad.");
                         break;

            case FRIDAY: System.out.println("Fridays are better.");
                         break;

            case SATURDAY:
            case SUNDAY: System.out.println("Weekends are best.");
                         break;

            default:     System.out.println("Midweek days are so-so.");
                         break;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EnumTest firstDay = new EnumTest(Day.MONDAY);
        firstDay.tellItLikeItIs();
        EnumTest thirdDay = new EnumTest(Day.WEDNESDAY);
        thirdDay.tellItLikeItIs();
        EnumTest fifthDay = new EnumTest(Day.FRIDAY);
        fifthDay.tellItLikeItIs();
        EnumTest sixthDay = new EnumTest(Day.SATURDAY);
        sixthDay.tellItLikeItIs();
        EnumTest seventhDay = new EnumTest(Day.SUNDAY);
        seventhDay.tellItLikeItIs();


    }
}
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

The above code does not work without void.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method tellItLikeItIs() is undefined for the type EnumTest
```

What did I miss out?
Why is there a void in there?
And it does return a string?

Comment: All methods in Java must be one return type. void tell's to the VM that that specific method will not return anything.

Comment: They picked void because it goes hand and hand with "null". I would have preferred they used "empty" (which sounds awkward, but wouldn't if we'd've been using it for 20 or 30 years.)

Comment: You cannot remove the word `void` here because that's what the structure of the language requires. Definitions of methods expect you to specify the return type; you *have* to write it down somewhere. And that's just in front of the method name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason the code will not work without `void` is because the `System.out.println(String string)` method returns nothing and just prints the supplied arguments to the standard out terminal, which is the computer monitor in most cases. When a method returns "nothing" you have to specify that by putting the `void` keyword in its signature.

You can see the documentation of the System.out.println here:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.String%29

To press the issue further, println is a classic example of a method which is performing computation as a "side effect."

Answer (score 15):

You mean the `tellItLikeItIs` method? Yes, you have to specify `void` to specify that the method *doesn't* return anything. All methods *have* to have a return type specified, even if it's `void`.

It certainly doesn't return a string - look, there are no return statements anywhere. It's not really clear why you think it *is* returning a string. It's *printing* strings to the console, but that's not the same thing as returning one from the method.

Answer (score 1):

When the return type is void, your method doesn't return anything.

Look again at your code: There's no return in that method.  You print to the console and exit.

Answer (score 0):

Void doesn't return anything; it tells the compiler the method doesn't have a return value.

Answer (score 0):

`void` means it returns nothing.  It does not return a string, you write a string to `System.out` but you're not returning one.

You must specify what a method returns, even if you're just saying that it returns nothing.

Technically speaking they could have designed the language such that if you don't write a return type then it's assumed to return nothing, however making you explicitly write out `void` helps to ensure that the lack of a returned value is intentional and not accidental.

Comment: How is it different when you say, a method returns nothing but it prints something on Console

Answer (score 0):

Void: the type modifier void states that the main method does not return any value. All parameters to a method are declared inside a prior of parenthesis. Here  String args[ ] declares a parameter named args which contains an array of objects of the class type string.