# Why does java use void?

Tags: java, void

I am well aware that the void keyword is used to indicate in a method declaration that the method will return no value.  My question is not about - to use an analogy - how to use the car, but rather about what's underneath the hood.  I would like to know why void actually needs to be specified, i.e. does Java reserve an internal variable of some sort to keep track of return types?  Will setting a method to void make it so that it doesn't have to do this?

*Another way to put it* is to ask why, exactly, can't Java omit the void keyword and assume that if there is no returned type than the method is void?  I think that there is something to do with how Java might "prepare" to handle the return type, and possibly something to do with optimization... please use full detail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367381/what-does-void-do-in-java

Comment: If you'd omit void, it'd be a constructor, it is simply a way to keep the syntax and parser simple: all methods have a return type, even if they don't return anything.

Comment: If you want to see whats under the hood, you can just look at the source code. As for why methods have return types, Mark is correct.

Comment: its just syntax.and yes, clear syntax helps compilers to do things easily and without ambiguation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does a return key word do in a void method in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744676/what-does-a-return-key-word-do-in-a-void-method-in-java)

Comment: If somebody could please tell me how my question introduces a bias, I would be able to fix it.  At the moment, just putting it on hold isn't good enough.  I have no idea how my question can be construed as opinionated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my answer is a bit of a guess. But I'd say its to protect the developer against just forgetting to declare the return type. Sure the compiler can even by default be programmed to render undeclared return types void. But that would be at cost to the aid for the developer.

Furthermore, IDEs would have to anticipate on the same.

Answer (score 2):

Its a java language Specification
`void` used with only methods declaration

if we omit `void` then its treated as constructor.

SEE [THIS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: My God, this solved a lot of pain I was having. I can now use super  and I now understand why super only works when you omit void from the constructor and why it works being omitted.