# Void is invalid for the variable main?

Tags: java

How do i fix the error, Void is invalid for the variable main? I tried looking this up online but couldn't find anything. Also I am kind of new to this so please take it easy on me. I am learning as I go.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class Text extends JFrame
{


   JPanel jp = new JPanel();
   JLabel jl = new JLabel();
   JTextField jt = new JTextField("Month",30);
   JTextField jt2 = new JTextField("Date",30);
   JButton jb = new JButton("Enter");

   public Text()
   {
       public static void main (String[] args); {
          setTitle("Tutorial");
          setVisible(true);
          setSize(400, 200);
          setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

          jp.add(jt);
          jp.add(jt2);


          jt.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
          {
                 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                 {
                       String input = jt.getText();
                       jl.setText(input); 
                 }
          });

          jp.add(jb);
          jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
          {
                  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                  {


                         String input = jt.getText();
                         String input2 = jt2.getText();
                         jl.setText(input);
                         jl.setText(input2);
                         int day = Integer.parseInt(input2);
                            if ((input.equals("Test")) && (input2.equals(day >= 26)))//||(input2.equals("27")))))
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "" , "" ,JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,aries);
                  }

          });


          add(jp);

   }

   }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does void do in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367381/what-does-void-do-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Java doesnt allow methods to be defined within other methods. Move the `main` method out of the `Text` constructor and remove the semi-colon which is terminating the statement early.

In addition you have a number of methods (e.g. `setTitle` and `setVisible`) which belong to the `JFrame` - these need to be moved to an instance code block to make them are accessible.

```
public class Text extends JFrame {

    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    JLabel jl = ...

    public Text() {
        setTitle("Tutorial");
        setVisible(true);
        ...

        add(jp);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Text().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have placed your `main` method *inside* the constructor for `class Text`. It belongs outside the constructor, at the same level as the constructor.  Move it outside the constructor.

```
public class Text extends JFrame
{


   JPanel jp = new JPanel();
   JLabel jl = new JLabel();
   JTextField jt = new JTextField("Month",30);
   JTextField jt2 = new JTextField("Date",30);
   JButton jb = new JButton("Enter");

   public static void main (String[] args); {
      setTitle("Tutorial");
      setVisible(true);
      setSize(400, 200);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      ...
   }

   public Text()
   {
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `;` after the `main` method declaration:

```
public static void main (String[] args);
                                       ^-------- Delete this
```

And put the `main` method out of the constructor:

```
public Text() {
...
}

public static void main(...) {
...
}
```