# I cannot understand the purpose of using and not using "void",(what does returning a value mean?"

Tags: java, methods, void, public

so in this code we have three methods and I dont understand why we use voids in two of the methods and dont in one
can someone explain with **detail**

```
class Point {

private double anan;
private double baban;

public void print(){
    System.out.println("(" + anan + "," + baban + ")");


}
public Point(double anan, double baban) {
    this.anan = anan;
    this.baban = baban;


}

public void scale(){
    anan = anan/2;
    baban = baban/2;

}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Comment: void means that method not returning anything

Comment: One of the methods is a constructor.

Comment: also see; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367381/what-does-void-do-in-java

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_type

Answer (score 1):

Constructor dont have returntype

```
public Point(double anan, double baban) {}  // is a constructor
public void print(){}   // is a method
public void scale(){}   // is a method
```

From the [Providing Constructors for Your Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) , [Deifining Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

> **Constructor** declarations look like method declarations—except that
>   they use the name of the class and have no return type
>
> The only required elements of a **method** declaration are the
>   method's return type, name, a pair of parentheses, (), and a body
>   between braces, {}.
>
> The return type—the data type of the value returned by the method, or
>   **void** if the method does not return a value.

Answer (score 1):

When a method does not return something then return type should be void.

As your method `Point()`

```
public Point(double anan, double baban) {
    this.anan = anan;
    this.baban = baban;
}
```

is the constructor method, so there has no return type.

Here is a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19061630/2317535) about Methods vs Constructors

> > The important difference between constructors and methods is that constructors create and initialize objects that don't exist yet, while methods perform operations on objects that already exist.
> >
> > Constructors can't be called directly; they are called implicitly when the new keyword creates an object. Methods can be called directly on an object that has already been created with new.
> >
> > The definitions of constructors and methods look similar in code. They can take parameters, they can have modifiers (e.g. public), and they have method bodies in braces.
> >
> > Constructors must be named with the same name as the class name. They can't return anything, even void (the object itself is the implicit return).
> >
> > Methods must be declared to return something, although it can be void.

For further reading see [methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) and [constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).